# dynamically resize image using jquery in wp

Tags: jquery, dynamic, resize, image-resizing, window-resize

I'm new here, and have been using this forum and learning a lot. I have a problem and I hope you guys can help me. I am working on a website, it's based on WP and WPEC.

What I'm trying to do is to make the image in the product modal view to resize dynamically (when user change/resize browser vertically and horizontally the image will resize).

I have managed to get the function working on window resize. HOWEVER, the catch is, when on load it still show the actual dimension (800x1200), not fitting to the browser size. And then when i drag the browser then it resizes (as it should be on window.resize)

I have tried adding DOM to resize, but it just killed my other function (hover on products page) which i need to be working to be able to open the modal view.

anyways, heres the code for the resize:

```
function resize() {



var w, h, conwidth, conheight, imgheight, imgwidth, top, left;
w = $(window).width();
h = $(window).height();
conwidth = w - 0;
if(conwidth < 493){ conwidth = 493; }
conheight = h - 0;
conratio = conwidth/conheight;
imgwidth = 800;
imgheight = 1204;
imgratio = 800/1204;
if(conratio < imgratio){
    width = conwidth;
    height = conwidth / imgratio;
} else {
    height = conheight;
    width = conheight * imgratio;
}
if(width > imgwidth || height > imgheight){
    width = imgwidth;
    height = imgheight;
}

top = (h/2) - (height/2);
left = (w/2) - (width/2);
if(left < 130){left = 130; }



$(".slideshow-content").css("position","fixed").css("margin",0);
$(".slideshow-content").css("top",0).css("left",0).css("height",height+"px").css("width",width+"px");
$(".psp-active").css("position","fixed").css("margin",0);
$(".psp-active").css("top",0).css("left",left+"px").css("height",height+"px").css("width",width+"px");
$(".slideshow-content img").css("left",left+"px").css("width",width+"px").css("height",height+"px");
```

}

See [this attempt](http://www.mickkmg.com/wordpress/store)

I hope its not too difficult, and maybe its just a piece of line missing, but i've been pulling my hair coz of this...

thanks a lot guys!